# 1px vertical lines appearing on website using Chrome on rMBP

Tags: html, google-chrome, rendering

When browsing a website I developed on Chrome on a Retina Macbook Pro, these vertical lines appear on the page. My website uses some cool parallax techniques, and these vertical lines make the background transparent, so you can see the background layer beneath them, which is annoying. Even if I turn off this background, you can still see the lines, just they're now white, not the background colour. The website is [www.1000days.me](http://1000days.me) and below I have included a screenshot (from the Chrome Emulator as I don't have an rMBP).

[image: The vertical lines I'm seeing on the right of the screenshot]

There is a container inside each `<section>` (every time the background colour changes, it's a new `<section>`) but these lines are outside the boundary lines of the container. Also, I can't confirm this, but on different resolutions, the lines seem to be in different places.

EDIT: also appears on Opera (I assume because it now uses Blink), but doesn't appear on Safari, Firefox or Internet Explorer.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without a [mcve].